# HSQLDB and log4j

Tags: java, log4j, hsqldb

I am using embedded type of hsqldb, and i would like to use log4j for all log output. All other classes use correctly my log4j configuration. But some reason hsqldb still outputs on console!

```
<logger name="org.hsqldb">
    <level value="FATAL" />
</logger>

<root>
    <priority value="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="R" />
</root>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what i end up doing...

```
        server = new Server();
        if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
            server.setSilent(false);
            server.setTrace(true);
        } else {
            server.setLogWriter(null);
            server.setSilent(true);
            server.setTrace(false);
        }
```

Comment: And what it gives?